# AWS Lambda - Health Check private ip:port in a vpc private subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc, health-monitoring

I am attempting to perform a health check on a specific port and ip of a private ec2 instance inside a vpc.

How would I go about this? I made some python attempts but have been unsuccessful so far. Would nodejs be a better alternative for this problem?

Comment: Is your lambda deployed inside a VPC? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc.html

Comment: Yes it is, I used this method though - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-access-resources-in-a-vpc-from-your-lambda-functions/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the module socket

```
import socket

IP = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 80

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
result = sock.connect_ex((IP,PORT))
if result == 0:
    print(f'Port {PORT} is open on {IP}')
else:
    print(f'Port {PORT} is closed on {IP}')
```

Comment: to handle timeout add sock.settimeout(2); before setting result variable and after the else statement sock.close()

Comment: Is there a way to add a path after port for ping? i.e. check xxx.xx.x.xxx : PORT/somethinghere

Comment: I have a security group configured to allow traffic on ports 80, 443, 22 (SSH) and 3306 (MySQL) from anywhere. It returns '0' only for 80, 22 and for rest any other port, it returns 1. Any idea why 443 and 3306 are failing?

Comment: I've no idea, but I suggest to double-check if you have other security groups that are denying that rule. Also check your network ACL (I generally never use them, I use only security groups).

Answer (score 0):

Lambda function used in CloudFormation Template to validate privateIP:port,
Lambda function to validate the private IP with port 443.

````
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: index.lambda_handler
      Role: !Ref lambdaRole
      Code:
        ZipFile: !Sub |
          import json
          import boto3
          import socket
          PORT = [443]
          DNS = ['${PrimaryIP}']

          def lambda_handler(event, context):

              try:
                  for iDNS in DNS:
                      for iport in PORT:
                          sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                          output = sock.connect_ex((iDNS,iport))
                          if output == 0:
                              return True
                          else:
                              return False
                  sock.close()
              except:
                  print('Task timed out')
      Runtime: python3.8
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: 'PostCheckFunction'
      Timeout: 10
      TracingConfig:
        Mode: Active
      VpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - !Ref LambdaSecurityGroupID
        SubnetIds:
          - !Ref PrivateSubnet1ID
    DependsOn: PrivateInstance```
````